# find_package(OpenSSL) unable to find specific libssl version

Tags: c++, c, cmake, build, openssl

I'm working on a RHEL7 system with OpenSSL versions 1.0.2k and 0.9.8e installed:

```
$ ll /usr/lib64/libssl.so*   
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Feb 28 19:32 /usr/lib64/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 340832 Mar  4  2016 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 470360 Apr  9  2019 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Feb 28 19:31 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jun 22  2018 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
```

For compatibility reasons, my program needs to link against the old 0.9.8e version, but [`find_package()` for OpenSSL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindOpenSSL.html) does not seem able to find it.
If I use `find_package(OpenSSL 0.9.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS SSL Crypto)` it finds the newer version:

```
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so (found suitable version "1.0.2k", minimum required is "0.9.8") found components: SSL Crypto
```

If I add the `EXACT` option, CMake tells me that the version could not be found:

```
CMake Error at /path/to/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "1.0.2k", but
  required is exact version "0.9.8" (found /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so)
```

Looking at the output it is evident that `FindOpenSSL.cmake` is only looking at the symlink that points to the newer library. Providing `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` is no option either, as both libraries reside in the same directory. Is it possible to tell the command to look for a specific library/SONAME?

I don't feel like directly linking against the correct library. Should I report a bug to KitWare? To me it looks like the command is broken in this respect.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the source code for the finder module for OpenSSL. I have had to do similar for other modules.

Comment: `find_package` looks for the `libssl.so` link. Yours points to 1.0.2. Even if you manually change it, unless you also have header files installed, it won't work. You need a full development environment for openssl 0.9.8 installed. I do not recall whether RHEL7 provides development packages for 0.9.8. They might be shipping only runtime 0.9.8 libraries to support software built for earlier versions of RHEL only. In which case your only option is to build openssl yourself, from scratch, and install it in a manner that won't turn your RHEL7 system into an unbootable brick.

Comment: @drescherjm unfortunately that doesn't work. So-called letter releases are not (syntactically) supported here. It is an error if I add the 'e'.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik lets assume I do it this way. Wouldn't that still be an issue because my binary will search for `libssl.so` rather than `libssl.so.0.9.8e` when being executed? Actually that's another issue that I'm facing with a binary that was built on a RHEL5 machine, where 0.9.8.e is the default version. When run on the RHEL7 system, it loads the wrong `libssl` version and segfaults.

Comment: Your binary will not search for `libssl.so`. At link time, the complete shared library version gets read from the `.so` file, which should be `libssl.so.6` here, and that's what will be searched at runtime. There's a reason for all these symlinks here. I don't know what was happening on RHEL5, it's possible that openssl wasn't built correctly back then.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to upgrade your application to become compatible with openssl 1.0.x or 1.1.x.

That being said, in the spirit of answering this question, you can do the following:

```
mkdir $HOME/openssl0.9.8e && cd $_
wget http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/CentOS/openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.4.x86_64.rpm
wget http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/CentOS/openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.4.x86_64.rpm
for i in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $i | cpio -idmv; done
cd ..

# If you are using CMake 2.x
cmake -S /path/to/your/project -Bbuild \
   -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/openssl0.9.8e/usr/include \
   -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=$HOME/openssl0.9.8e/usr/lib64/libssl.so \
   -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=$HOME/openssl0.9.8e/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so

# If you are using CMake 3.x
cmake3 -S /path/to/your/project -Bbuild -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$HOME/openssl0.9.8e/usr
```

`OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` can't be properly used with 2.x because of a [fix](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/12d6eb639d3fc7dd9b9a1280d462a47c5f123120#diff-fe8d6d3a9cfe5f0d0dcdab3824900232L275) which is available only in 3.x.

Sample content for the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(so)

find_package(OpenSSL 0.9.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS SSL Crypto EXACT)

add_executable(main main.x.c)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

To run the binary after building it, you can either install the compat package: `openssl098e` on CentOS7/RHEL7 or use:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/openssl0.9.8e/lib64 /path/to/build/main
```

Please note that you'll also need to install `krb5-devel` as it is a dependency for using `libssl`.

You can also vendor the libraries along with your application and have `$ORIGIN` in `RPATH`, but I'll leave that as an exercise (for fun) and highly not recommend it as you should update your app to make it complaint with openssl 1.0.x or 1.1.x and since you won't be getting any updates for 0.9.8 libs, ever, so it is a huge security concern.